# Delete attachment from an e-mail being edited

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm writing a macro, that is designed to be run on an e-mail, that is currently *being edited*.

The problem I'm facing is, that I can't delete attachments. I get **`80030002 error`**.

Here is my code

```
Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
c = myItem.Attachments.Count
For i = c To 1 Step -1
    Set myAttachment = myItem.Attachments.Item(i)
    If myAttachment.Type = OlAttachmentType.olByValue Then
        myItem.Attachments.Remove (i)
    End If
Next
```

After running this code, working deleting attachments manually results in a crash of Outlook.

My question is: How can I delete attachments from the e-mail being currently edited?

*Microsoft Office Standard 2010*

Comment: The error code is STG_E_FILENOTFOUND. Does this happen when you open an MSG file?

Comment: I don't open any files. I click "compose new e-mail", drop some files into the new empty e-mail and then run the script above. That's it! Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead :

```
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
c = myAttachments.Count
For i = c To 1 Step -1
    Set myAttachment = myAttachments.Item(i)
    If myAttachment.Type = OlAttachmentType.olByValue Then
        myAttachment.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, same result :( Any other ideas?